# While connecting telnet I got errors like "556 5.7.5 Invalid RFC missing body"

Tags: email, smtp, telnet, yahoo, rfc

I tried to verify an email address using SMTP for all mailboxes it's working fine except for Yahoo email ID. While connecting telnet I got errors like "556 5.7.5 Invalid RFC missing body".
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, Jayashree.

The error message you are receiving is related to your test email not having a body part. The body part begins immediately after 2 `<CRLF><CRLF>` following the `Content-Transfer-Encoding`.

It begins at `Good morning.` and ends at `P | 999.555.1234`

Below is a complete example of a properly formatted `text/plain` email.

```
To: "Jane Doe" <jane@example1.com>
From: "John Doe" <john@example1.com>
Subject: A text/plain email
MIME-Version: 1.0 (Created with SublimeText 3)
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Good morning.

This is a message in text/plain format.
It contains text/plain.
It contains no base64 inline images or attachments.
Each line is no more than 76 characters in length.

Please reach out if you have any questions.


Thank you,

John Doe
SENIOR DEVELOPER
XYZ Solutions Inc.
P | 999.555.1234
```

Comment: If we give data mail is send to the user. How to validate the user ID without sending an email?